# Cisco ASA5505 ASDM Access Issues

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I am installing Cisco firewall solution ASA5505. but cannot access user interface. I navigate to  ASA5505 local website 192.168.1.1 from Windows 7 connecting to ASA5505. After the navigating, Java loads appliance but then says "Cannot Load". Please help. I try rebooting ASA5505 but problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're describing lies with the Java settings of your Windows machine, not the ASA appliance.  Change the Java security permissions (under Configure Java > Security) and make an exception to the IP address of the ASA port which was configured to accept the HTTPS connections from the ASDM.  Assign a static address to the Windows machine - don't use DHCP - and allow it to access the ASA.